# Battery Level Indicator

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage, batteries

I am using 3 AA batteries of 1.5V each, to obtain a voltage of 4.5V which i am then reducing to 3.3V using a LDO. My current requirement is around 100mA.

I want a simple, **low** power dissipation circuit which would be connected to the arduino to monitor this battery level

Previously for one of my projects I have used a simple zener diode to monitor the battery level. However I didn't take into account the heat dissipation, reliability etc.

So, can I know what are the different types of options available?
My main constraints are:-
1)Circuit should be simple
2)Low power dissipation

I am attaching the pics of my entire circuit and the zener circuit which i used before.[image: Entire Circuit[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKZSo.png)

To provide a bit of background of the zener circuit, I first calibrate it for my application, then I am able to view the percentage of battery at the display.

Comment: LD is reversed. If Arduino runs on 5V you can read LED-battery voltage with ANALOGIN function. Why not use Arrduino supply for LEDs? Alkaline cells range from 1.65V/cell down to 1V when exhausted.  LDO will drop out at low end.

Comment: Is there any chance you can rotate the image correctly? You will get a lot more readers.

Comment: Many questions in here about this, just one: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/19355/152903

Comment: @RussellMcMahon LD is a zener. it is oriented correctly.

Comment: It's actually a zener diode not a LED @ Russell McMahon

Comment: @SolarMike Already checked that link , there is no circuit provided over there to monitor the battery level.

Comment: Using a zener in that manner is unlikely to give an accurate result - except perhaps with much more circuitry. | If the load can be tolerated a simple 2 resistor divider will suffice. | If the divider load causes excessive drain overall a high side switch can be added that enable the divider - as shown by Jasen. This connects the R2 R3 divider when required via Q1 and disconnects it when Q1 is off.
Q1 is turned on by Q2 collector low = Q2 base high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting the GPIO high turns on Q1 and Q2 presenting half the battery voltage to the analog input.

setting the GPIO it low turns off Q1 and Q2 avoiding unneeded drain on the battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQLPMi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am a bit confused, will this circuit help me in displaying the battery level status in the arduino or does it act like a level detector?

Comment: it sends a representation of the battery level to the arduino on request.

Comment: You likely need one more resistor, from base of Q1 to its emitter.

Comment: modern transirors have very low leakage but that wouldn't hurt  added R5

Comment: Thanks a lot Jasen , simulated the circuit also, one final doubt since my transistor is basically acting like a switch can i use any transistor model or are there any constraints?

Comment: Any small PNP model: PN200, 2N3906, BC557 etc.

Comment: How did u actually choose the values for R3,R4,R5, I am assuming that the output voltage was one of design factors , what else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple voltage divider, with an optional voltage follower/buffer opamp (A lot of low power options are available).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4j4kh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The opamp and Zener are optional but are good design considerations. Especially the opamp will reduce the source impedance of the reference voltage. (as recommended by Arduino for its ADC).